# Asp.NET MVC Session count goes back to 0 after button click

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, session-state

I am using Sessions in ASP.NET MVC4 and i am storing some data in session, everything works well until i click a button and all the sessions in the applications becomes null.

```
<button id="btnExport">Export To Excel</button>

$('#btnExport').click(function () {
        window.location.href = "/Home/DownloadFile?Id=2";
});
```

As soon as i hit the Action Method in my controller all the sessions in the application are null. i have tried using Ajax GET request instead of window.location.href.

here is my web.config setting

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" mode="InProc" timeout="60" />
```

and in Global.asax i have this

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["init"] = 0;
}
```

and i am checking the Count

```
var sessionCount = Session.Count;
```

Also using visual studio watch window to monitor my session object.

I am using windows authentication.

can you guys please help, why sessions are deleted on button request?

Thanks

Comment: how do you know whether it is deleted/gone ? How are you verifying that ?

Comment: Visual Studio Watch Window. i am watching total count of my sessions also i am checking if my session becomes null or not.all the sessions becomes null.

Comment: You need to show that code so that people might be able to help

Comment: i have edited my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the concept. `Session_start()` will be fired always, which will lead to reinitialize your session value to `0`.

***Workaround***: Create a base controller and inherit this into every controller you make.  Override `OnActionExecuting()` function in base controller and then manipulate your session. Also the session in MVC resides on  the current Controller context so use it widely